# Get Frame's element on another page view

Tags: nativescript

i have some Frame that points to dashboard/dashboard/dashboard:

```
<Page class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="load">
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <Frame defaultPage="dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/" id="dashboard"></Frame>
    <GridLayout row="1">
        <StackLayout verticalAlignment="bottom" row="2" class="bottom-nav">
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*" height="70">

                <Label class="icon4 foot-icon" row="0" col="0" id="ico4"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Now, i would like to use dashboard.js to target this Frame's element (ico4) in this case. All i want is to select this and add css class for this.
But nothing works for me. I've tried this but without sucess:

dashboard.js:

```
var frame = require('ui/frame');
var topmost = frame.getFrameById('dashboard').getElementById('ico4');
var ic = topmost;
console.log(ic);
```

My question is - is this possible to target this ico4 in any way?
Thank you.

Edit:
I've Tried your path @Nick Iliev, but for me ico is undefined...

```
    var frame = require('ui/frame');
    var myFrame = frame.getFrameById("dashboard");

    // Its working the output :Frame<dashboard>@file:///app/dashboard/root.xml:3:5;
    console.log(myFrame);

    var myPage = myFrame.currentPage;
    // It's working too
    console.log(myPage);

    var ico = myPage.getViewById("ico4");

    // Not working - Undefined...
```

### console.log(ico);

EDIT: I've added simple playground to show my problem: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=uVY4Ir

```
//app-root.xml (frame has ID)

<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="load">
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <Frame defaultPage="home/home-page" id="dashboard"></Frame>
    <GridLayout row="1">
        <StackLayout verticalAlignment="bottom" row="2" class="bottom-nav">
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*,*,*,*,*,*" height="70">
                <Label id="ico1" text="test"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Now home-page.js

```
var frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");
var HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;

  var root = frameModule.getFrameById('dashboard');
// this console.log will show frame's info
  console.log(root);
// But this below undefined. Why the frame cannot find this element ?

  var ico = root.getViewById('ico1');
  console.log(ico);
}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** `getElementById` in `tns-core-modules` but there is **a page method** called **`getViewById`**. To use it you will need to get the page reference through your current frame reference.

Here is an example of how to get the current page in a selected frame.

```
const frame = getFrameById("my-frame-id");
const page = frame.currentPage;
let ico = page.getViewById("ico4");
```

Comment: For me this simple code will work only at root.js :
var ico = page.getViewById('ico4');
console.log(ico);

But for me there is no way to access this frame element from another pages than root frame itself....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'there is no way to access this frame element from another pages than root frame itself'. Create a Playground demo to better illustrate your specific issue https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: Hi @Nick , its' here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=uVY4Ir. home-page.js has the code, and mainly console.log(ico); is not working.

Comment: I need to have this, beacuse from some page i want to select this frame's alement and add active class.

Comment: getFrameById() is deprecated. Use Frame.getFrameById() instead.